# Delete a sheet based on a cell value, but delete a different sheet than Active Sheet (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table filled with data, and I have multiple sheets that are named the exact the same as cells in column B in that table. I want to delete sheets if the value in column I is equal to a manually inputted value of "A", "B", "C", or "D". How do I delete the sheets based on the name found in column B if the value in column I of that same row is equal to any of those 4 letters?

I could only find ways to deleting rows, and I'm completely new to VBA so I don't know where to go from here

Comment: What is the tab or code name of the worksheet with the table? Is the table a structured (Excel) table or just a range in table format i.e. one row of headers? If it's a structured table, what is its name? Will the code be in the same workbook as the worksheets?

Comment: It's a range, not a structured table. The Name of the sheet is "Summary Report This Month". The code would be in the same workbook as the worksheets. All the worksheets are located on the same workbook.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub DeleteSheet()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "I") = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A") _
        Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "I") = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B") _
        Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "I") = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "C") _
        Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "I") = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "D") Then
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B") <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                'delete the sheet with the name in column B
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B")).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Sheets From a List With Additional Criterion

```vb
Sub DeleteSheets()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Sheets"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Summary Report This Month" ' do not delete!!!
    Const SRC_FIRST_NAMES_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const SRC_CRITERION_COLUMN As String = "I"
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_LIST As String = "A,B,C,D"
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_NAMES_CELL)
    Dim snrg As Range: Set snrg = sws.Range( _
        sfCell, sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sfCell.Column).End(xlUp))
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = snrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_CRITERION_COLUMN)
    'Debug.Print snrg.Address, scrg.Address
    
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(SRC_CRITERIA_LIST, ",")
    Dim rIndexes(): rIndexes = Application.Match(scrg, Criteria, 0)
    
    Dim dsh As Object, r As Long, shCount As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(rIndexes)
        If IsNumeric(rIndexes(r, 1)) Then ' criteria met
            On Error Resume Next
                Set dsh = wb.Sheets(CStr(snrg.Cells(r).Value))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not dsh Is Nothing Then ' sheet exists
                If StrComp(dsh.Name, SRC_SHEET, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    'Debug.Print "Deleted """ & dsh.Name & """."
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete w/o confirmation
                        dsh.Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                    shCount = shCount + 1
                    Set dsh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
                'Else ' it's the source worksheet; do nothing
                End If
            'Else  ' sheet doesn't exist; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' criteria not met; do nothing
        End If
    Next r
        
    MsgBox shCount & " sheet" & IIf(shCount = 1, "", "s") & " deleted.", _
        IIf(shCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation), PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Imagine you have this table in a sheet named `Main`

```
+---+---+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| . | A |   B    | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
+---+---+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   | Apple  |   |   |   |   |   |   | A |
| 2 |   | Sheet2 |   |   |   |   |   |   | B |
| 3 |   | Tree   |   |   |   |   |   |   | C |
| 4 |   | Dog    |   |   |   |   |   |   | D |
| 5 |   | Bird   |   |   |   |   |   |   | A |
| 6 |   | Sheet6 |   |   |   |   |   |   | A |
+---+---+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Also, you have sheets in your workbook, named:

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet4
Sheet5
Sheet6
Main
```

So you want to delete sheets named `Sheet2` and `Sheet6`, because their names appear in column `B` and also in column `I` appears a letter between `A, B, C, D`

Remember every letter has a value (ASCII codes) and this little table had the values for each letter you need.

```
+---+----+
| A | 65 |
| B | 66 |
| C | 67 |
| D | 68 |
+---+----+
```

Check this: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Now into a normal module put this code:

```
Sub Delete_Sheets()
    'Store the whole workbook
    Dim Wrk         As Workbook: Set Wrk = ThisWorkbook
    'Store the main sheet where you have your table (I guess so...)
    Dim Main        As Worksheet: Set Main = Wrk.Worksheets("Main")
    Dim Sht         As Worksheet
    Dim i           As Range
    Dim ShtNames    As Range
    Dim RngLetter   As Range
    Dim StrLetter   As String
    Dim NumLetter   As Integer
    'Find the last row in column B, and also (guess) the table begins in row 2
    Dim LRow: LRow = Main.Range(Main.Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), Main.Cells(Rows.Count, "B")).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim iR
    'Set the range from column B to the last cell
    Set ShtNames = Main.Range(Main.Cells(2, "B"), Main.Cells(LRow, "B"))
    'Let's loop!
    For Each i In ShtNames
        'Get the row of the cell in column B
        iR = i.Row
        'Get the cell in column I in the same row.
        Set RngLetter = Main.Cells(iR, "I")
        'Set the letter to capital from the value. We need A instead of a
        StrLetter = UCase(RngLetter.Value)
        'Take the ASCII value of the letter A=65 B=66 C=67 and so on.
        NumLetter = Asc(StrLetter)
        'Another loop...
        'Now with the value in the cells from columns B and I, let's check.
        For Each Sht In Wrk.Worksheets
            'If the name of the sheet is equal to the cell in column B
            'and NumLetter is between 65 and 68
            'Remember ASC("A") returns 65
            If Sht.Name = i.Value And NumLetter >= Asc("A") And NumLetter <= Asc("D") Then
                'Don't show the alerts!
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                'Delete the sheet!
                Sht.Delete
                'Turn on the alerts
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next Sht
    Next i
End Sub
```